# How do I change the default backup folder in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I'm using the built-in Windows Backup. The default destination folder (backup location\computer name\Backup Set year-month-day time) is unsuitable for me because I already have got some other files in that location and I'd prefer to keep them there.

I found no way to change it. Is it possible to have a backup on the same partition but in a different folder? Or do I have to store backups on a different disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Backup allows you specify what drive to store backup data on. Unfortunately, you cannot change the directory hierarchy. Depending on what edition of Windows 7 you're using, you may have the ability to save to a network location, which could be a shared folder on your machine.

Comment: +1 for the info, -billions to micro$**t for their stupidity. I tried sharing a folder on my external drive and setting *that* up as the destination, but winDoze backup refused to accept the login credentials even though there was an Explorer window open with the mapped drive in it.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I could think of was to use `subst` and create a virtual disk. I don't know if this is a good idea for backups.

Comment: Wasn't aware of subst before. +1 to you sir/ma'm.

Comment: nice option. It never occured to me that I could use this too.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution (workaround!)

I think, you have only one workaround for this problem, because the Windows Backup has not any settings or registry parameters for it.

*For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb891959(v=vs.85).aspx*

**You can use `subst` command to mount a directory as drive in backuped system and Windows Installer too.**

1. Make an auto running script with `subst` for always present backup drive.
2. Configure Windows Backup to use this drive
3. You are finished on backup site!

At restore:

1. Boot a Windows Installer.
2. Press `SHIFT`+`F10` for catch a command prompt.
3. Re-create the `subst` mount.
4. Exit from console
5. Start restore process from this drive.
6. Cheers! ;)

## Not preferred

Here are some methods what will work for backup, but you can restore files on working system only! Can not use these in Windows Installer / Recovery Partition!

- **Localhost network share:** You can share a local directory and make backup on local share.

  The Windows Installer environment is not supported make shares, so you can not make same environment for restore. *The required services are not available and the `net share` command will not work!*
- **VHD file:** You can mount a virtual disk image and can use it as backup destination.

  The `vhdmount` command is not present in installer, so you can not reach your recovery data.

***P.S:** Any backup are not worth anything, when I can not restore the original state!*

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question.

Comment: The subst way does not work anymore in windows 10, windows backup will give an internal error.

Comment: @engineercoding can you send me a screenshot or any details from this error?

Answer (score 0):

Hihi, did not try this, but it will be cool if it works :D I was also frustrated with backup naming and location (stupid backup polluting my partition root), but eventually i started making my backup on network and forgot about this. So you should try this:

- Create some folder where you want to
  place you backup
- Share this folder to yourself
- Select option to backup on network
  and give you shared folder as
  location, but not as local path as
  D:\FolderForBackup , you must use you
  network path as
  //MyComputerName/FolderForBackup

If this works than lol.

Comment: How to share a folder to yourself?

Comment: @fohrums Go to folder options, Share, AdvancedSharingOptions and add only you as user which can access this shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on Windows 7 Backup, and just created a Dynamic expanding VHD as B: in the Disk Manager, and used Robocopy.   :)  Windows Backup would not even recognize my non-active VHD it created either..  Sigh..

Comment: That works great for files, but it does not capture registry state, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I am running Windows 10 and using the legacy Windows 7 backup app. I wanted to use a different drive but that app didn't allow it. I deleted the partition on the designated backup drive and ran backup again (before creating a new partition on the old drive). Backup complained that the old drive was unavailable. Selecting the "Change setting" option allowed me to pick a new drive.